# Jhipster doesn't create 'jhipster' realm with keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, openid, keycloak

When starting keycloak using docker-compose, the 'master' realm is created but the 'jhipster' realm was not created. I see two files jhipster-realm.json and jhipster-users-0.json files. I can import them manually from the keycloak admin console. From what I remember, a project created a few months back imported 'jhipster' realm automatically. Did I do something wrong configuring the project?

Jhipster version: 6.5.1
Keycloak version: 7.0.0

The keycloak.yml is the default from the generator.

```
version: '2'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:7.0.0
    command:
      [
        '-b',
        '0.0.0.0',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING',
        '-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000',
      ]
    volumes:
      - ./realm-config:/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - DB_VENDOR=h2
    ports:
      - 9080:9080
      - 9443:9443
      - 10990:10990
```

The error while starting the app using `mvnw` command resulted in this error.

```
 Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the OpenID Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
        at com.ve.EducationApp.main(EducationApp.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

Comment: You need to check if the Docker volume is correctly mounted: `./realm-config:/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config`. Go into the container, go to `/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config` and try to list the files in this folder

Comment: There are no files in that directory.

[jboss@e66ad05f6efd realm-config]$ ls -l
total 0

Comment: it means the volume is not mounted correctly. Do you use Windows ? In this case, be sure your project is under your user folder, for example C:\Users\yourname, otherwise, I think you can have problem with volume

Comment: @PascalGrimaud Thank you very much. After I moved the project to c:\Users\,=<username> directory, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same issue, when i opened shell in container realm and user files were not there and not getting imported, seemed to be some mount issue.  However it started working for me when i updated my docker compose file version which was set to older version i.e. '2' to version: '3.7' and it worked like  charm.